# Trying to remove my last input from a Label's text

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am working on a shopping register, I am trying to make it so that if I try to remove an item I entered, the function removes the last item that was input to the tkinter label or to the `'item_text_var'`. I understand this code isnt very clear. Basically, I am trying to get a function that can remove the last item added to a Label or a string var.

The code works until the `#`, It can remove the last price added from the total price, but I am unable to remove the last price's Label, or the text of the last item.

```
def remove_item():
    global item_text_var
    del total_prices_list[-1]
    total_price = 0
    for price in total_prices_list:
        total_price += price
    display_price = f"€{total_price:.2f}"
    total_price_display.set(display_price)
    #
    print(item_text_var)
    item_text_var -= total_prices_list[-1]
    print(item_text_var)
```

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, you can use the pop() function to remove items from the list. your_list.pop() would remove the last item in the list. You can pass the index of the item as well, pop(2), etc.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to remove the next to last element you could use your_list.pop(-2). This won't work if there is only one item in your list, so make sure you check that the length of the list is greater than 1.

Comment: Why don't you use a list to store those item text? Then you can delete the last item like how you delete the last price.